# Making a lightbox look like another box

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is not the best question to ask, I know, but I am really stuck on a problem with some lightboxes. I was trying to use this [Lightbox](http://codepen.io/cssjockey/pen/qsCkF) and it worked fine, however I couldn't have more than one lightbox as they all share the same divs etc. So I can only have a lightbox with same content.

Then I found this [lightbox1](http://codepen.io/mattsince87/pen/EjOKOO) Which is perfect, because you can see I can have more than 2 etc and easy, all I need to do is change the data-target for this one and I can have lost of lightboxes with different contents.

Example :

```
<div id="modaldemo" class="modal-wrap closed" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal">
        <a href="#" class="modal-close"></a>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Content Here -->
            <p>Hello World</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However I am struggling with the CSS on this lightbox.

So what I need help with, is to get the second lightbox, the one I want to use, and make it look like the first one, if that makes sense?

So just to make sure, I am using lightbox1 and I want that to look like a lightbox. But I don't understand the CSS and I can't seem to get it to change, so any help on this would be great.

P.S. if there is a way to make the first light box have different content then I am up for that as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed a couple of things so that the first lightbox can now have multiple panels. You can create and open them similiar to the 2nd lightbox example.

```
<!-- Set Target panel with data-target -->
<a class="show-panel" data-target="#panel1" href="#">Show Panel 1</a>

<!-- Define the panel with the id -->
<div class="lightbox-panel" id="panel1">
    <h2>Lightbox Panel 1</h2>
    <p>You can add any valid content here.</p>
    <p align="center"><a class="close-panel" href="#">Close this window</a></p>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d2ua864e/3/)

Comment: fanatic ty x so much